# How to save variables server side?

Tags: javascript

I want to save variables to the server so they can be converted back to client side later on other pcs, sort of like local storage but the data is available to all computers who use the site. I am still new to javascript and am learning new things.

Comment: Use a database or create some sort of global variable on your backend?

Comment: start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side

Comment: you will need a database

Comment: See [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](/q/13840429/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a database. A database is a constantly running server that can hold "tables" of data such as user info. If you are new to this concept I recommend google Firebase because it is a beginner friendly back end tool.